# Python InfluxDB2 - write_api.write(...) How to check for success?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, influxdb-python, influxdb-2

I need to write historic data into InfluxDB (I'm using Python, which is not a must in this case, so I maybe willing to accept non-Python solutions). I set up the write API like this

```
write_api = client.write_api(write_options=ASYNCHRONOUS)
```

The Data comes from a DataFrame with a timestamp as key, so I write it to the database like this

```
result = write_api.write(bucket=bucket, data_frame_measurement_name=field_key, record=a_data_frame)
```

This call does not throw an exception, even if the InfluxDB server is down. `result` has a protected attribute `_success` that is a boolean in debugging, but I cannot access it from the code.

How do I check if the write was a success?

Comment: Rant: How I hate this brave new eventbased world, where everything is "eventual consistency, or maybe never".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write_api.write()` returns a `multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult` or `multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult` (both are the same).

With this return object you can check on the asynchronous request in a couple of ways. See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult

If you can use a blocking request, then `write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCRONOUS)` can be used.

Answer (score 3):

If you use background batching, you can add custom success, error and retry callbacks.

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient

def success_cb(details, data):
    url, token, org = details
    print(url, token, org)
    data = data.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    print('Total Rows Inserted:', len(data))  

def error_cb(details, data, exception):
    print(exc)

def retry_cb(details, data, exception):
    print('Retrying because of an exception:', exc)    


with InfluxDBClient(url, token, org) as client:
    with client.write_api(success_callback=success_cb,
                          error_callback=error_cb,
                          retry_callback=retry_cb) as write_api:

        write_api.write(...)
```

If you are eager to test all the callbacks and don't want to wait until all retries are finished, you can override the interval and number of retries.

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, WriteOptions

with InfluxDBClient(url, token, org) as client:
    with client.write_api(success_callback=success_cb,
                          error_callback=error_cb,
                          retry_callback=retry_cb,
                          write_options=WriteOptions(retry_interval=60,
                                                     max_retries=2),
                          ) as write_api:
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to immediately write data into database, then use SYNCHRONOUS version of `write_api` - https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python/blob/58343322678dd20c642fdf9d0a9b68bc2c09add9/examples/example.py#L12

The asynchronous write should be "triggered" by call `.get()` - https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python#asynchronous-client

Regards

Comment: Your answer is not really correct, but it led me to the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

from influxdb_client import WritePrecision, InfluxDBClient, Point
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS

with InfluxDBClient(url="http://localhost:8086", token="my-token", org="my-org", debug=False) as client:
    p = Point("my_measurement") \
        .tag("location", "Prague") \
        .field("temperature", 25.3) \
        .time(datetime.utcnow(), WritePrecision.MS)

    try:
        client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS).write(bucket="my-bucket", record=p)
        reboot = False
    except Exception as e:
        reboot = True

    print(f"Reboot? {reboot}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).