# impot data from pandas dataframe to influxdb, but only get a measurement name, fields get nothing

Tags: pandas, dataframe, influxdb, influxdb-python

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    point = Point("measurement2") \
        .time(index, WritePrecision.NS)\
        .tag("tag_key", "1") \
        .field("hex", row["hex"]) \
        .field("PT4_BMS_Bat_Int_Res_Chrg_ST3", row["PT4_BMS_Bat_Int_Res_Chrg_ST3"]) \
        .field("PT4_BMS_Bat_Int_Res_Dschrg_ST3", row["PT4_BMS_Bat_Int_Res_Dschrg_ST3"]) \
        .field("PT4_BMS_Bat_SOC_Max_ST3", row["PT4_BMS_Bat_SOC_Max_ST3"]) \
        .field("PT4_BMS_Bat_SOC_Min_ST3", row["PT4_BMS_Bat_SOC_Min_ST3"]) \
        .field("PT4_BMS_Bat_SOC_ST3", row["PT4_BMS_Bat_SOC_ST3"]) \
        
    print(index)
    print(row["PT4_BMS_Bat_Int_Res_Chrg_ST3"])

    

    # import data
    write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org="benz", record=point)
    time.sleep(1) # separate points by 1 second
```

here is my dataframe

```
print(df.to_dict())
```

> {'hex': {Timestamp('2023-07-15 08:40:26.055830016'): '390e022affffffffffffffffffff0f80ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff470628c8e9ffffffff2a5867f00000', Timestamp('2023-07-15 08:40:27.056139008'): '390e022a69005900090bc15eda8f9e824146444f4a27c69d0581d790b6a3f8d7bc430628c8e9ffffffff952479340000', Timestamp('2023-07-15 08:40:28.056162048'): '390e022a69005900090bc15eda8f9e824146444f4a27c69d0581d790b6a3f8d7bc430628c8e9fffffffff915c4c50000', Timestamp('2023-07-15 08:40:29.056018944'): '390e022a69005900090bc15eda8f9e824146444f4a27c69d0581d790b6a3f8d7bc430628c8e9ffffffff5d9504930000', Timestamp('2023-07-15 08:40:30.056163072'):

there is no error output,but the fields still have no data

Comment: I fixed my question, is it clear now? I'm a rookie of this website

Comment: Better. I've suggested an edit that should further improve readability.

Comment: Helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69664307/12846804

Comment: Do dataframe cells contain dictionaries?

Comment: It help a lot, I think the problem is the format of the timestamp, where can I get the principle for the timestamp

Comment: All right, if you were to find the solution on your own, self-answering is encouraged here. [answer]

Comment: If you find the other post useful, please upvote it over there

Comment: I find that as long as the point contains timestamp, It turns fail. I still cant find the solution